# Entity Framework Core Many-to-Many Resolve Ambiguity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

What is the effective way to resolve ambiguity of [many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) relationships that point to the same entity either through annotations or fluent configuration? Given models such as:

```
public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Teams can be owned by multiple users
    public List<User> Owners { get; set; }
    // Teams can have multiple members
    public List<User> Members { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // User can own zero to many teams
    public List<Team> Owners { get; set; }
    // User can be a member of zero to many teams
    public List<Team> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Scaffolding results in an error along the lines of "Unable to determine the relationship by navigation "Team.Owners" of type "List".

Is this something that can be effectively resolved by manually creating [join entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#indirect-many-to-many-relationships) such as `TeamOwner` and `TeamMember` or would EF Core still struggle with ambiguity?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two Navigation properties on each entity, and EF doesn't have a convention to identify which goes with which.  So you need to configure the model to explicitly relate the navigation properties.  You'll also want to pick a descriptive name for the linking table.  EG:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   
    modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
                .HasMany(t => t.Owners)
                .WithMany(o => o.OwnerOf)
                .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("TeamOwners"));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
                .HasMany(t => t.Members)
                .WithMany(o => o.MemberOf)
                .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("TeamMembers"));


    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

You can relate the navigation properties with annotations, but can't name the linking table.  eg

```
public class Team
{
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(User.OwnerOf))]
    public List<User> Owners { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(User.MemberOf))]
    public List<User> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That resolved the error. Thank you for your help. Do you foresee this being possible to resolve via annotations?